# Is it possible to upload to App Store using Xcode 7.1 (beta)?

Tags: xcode, app-store, xcode7

I'm just preparing my app for iOS 9, prior to the new release next week, using latest beta version of Xcode but it gives me this error message:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you cannot with beta versions of Xcode (same as with previous beta versions of Xcode). Now the newest Xcode version is the `7.1 beta` which cannot be used for publishing apps. But there is `Xcode 7.0 GM` version and with this one it should be possible to publish app. Now when I am uploading apps it gives me same warning (`"Invalid Toolchain..."`; but I have it in testing for internal testers, I am uploading app via `Application Loader`) but it shouldn't take long and after few days Apple sends emails to developers that App Store now accepts iOS 9 versions of apps.