# Sorry Something Went Wrong this build is using a beta version of XCode and cant be submitted

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, xcode9.2

[image: iTunesConnect Test Flight Sorry Something Went Wrong this build is using a beta version of XCode and cant be submitted error message]

I uploaded a build and sent it to an external team in test flight a day ago.  I fixed a few bugs QA found and sent another build today, but when I went to send to an external team I got this error message and was blocked from deploying it to test flight.  I am on XCode 9.2 Mac 10.12.6 and I successfully sent a build over test flight 24-48 hours ago.

Comment: Apple doesn't allow AppStore submission from a beta version of Xcode. And well... you know... TestFlight requires an AppStore submission.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to upload to App Store using Xcode 7.1 (beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511858/is-it-possible-to-upload-to-app-store-using-xcode-7-1-beta) & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164388/xcode-beta-7-3-submission-to-itunes-connect-for-testflight & plenty others

Comment: Things go wrong at Apple, especially at times like now when a new version of Xcode is about to come out. Just wait a day or two and try again.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Bump build #, rebuild, upload, and try submitting app for review again

I ran into this issue as well.  I built the app using Xcode 9.2 (9C40b), which is a full release and not beta.  I attempted to submit the app for review and external testing multiple times at various points throughout the day, no luck, all failed.  I was able to submit for external testing yesterday, but today things stopped working.

After submitting a bug report to Apple about this, I received a response with the suggestion to bump the build number, rebuild the app, and upload it again to iTunes Connect/TestFlight.  After doing so, I was successful in submitting the app to our external testers group.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem today, and it didn't work after several retries. I managed to finally upload and deploy by using an older Xcode: Version 8.3.2 (8E2002).

Edit: In response to the comments on the post, this question is not a duplicate because xcode 9.2 is the current release. https://developer.apple.com/download/
It seems to be a bug by apple, because they don't usually suddenly stop accepting builds from release versions suddenly. Like I managed to upload and deploy it on version 8.3.2